# Do I need to watch Sin City 1 before watching Sin City 2?

Tags: sin-city, sin-city-a-dame-to-kill-for

I am about to watch Sin City: A Dame to Kill For.

I have absolutely no memory of the first movie. 9 years does that sometimes.

Is it important to watch Sin City 1 before Sin City 2? Do I need a recap?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Yes**. The film acts as both as sequel and prequel. [From the wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sin_City:_A_Dame_to_Kill_For#Production):

> Miller said the film would be a prequel and a sequel with interlinking
>   stories both before and after the first film. Miller, who was writing
>   the screenplay in 2006, had anticipated for production to begin later
>   in the year.

The new elements of the movie are discussed [here](http://www.cineworld.co.uk/blog/sin-city-2-prequel-sequel-equal), in article that was written *before* the film was released (so contains no spoilers). To quote from the article:

> Miller has said that the new film is based primarily on his story ***A
>   Dame to Kill For*** (the second in the series of books). This one centres
>   on Dwight (Josh Brolin) and takes place years before his storyline in
>   the first Sin City film (***The Big Fat Kill*** – the third in the series of
>   books), and before he needed the facial reconstruction surgery which
>   made him look like Clive Owen (who plays him in the first film).

It also states:

> One of the storylines is based on this short story, collected in the
>   book ***Booze, Broads & Bullets***, which is the fifth in the series. This
>   is Marv’s story...

Additionally:

> Along with the original stories, there will also be two new ones
>   written by Miller especially for this film. ***The Long Bad Goodnight*** is
>   Joseph Gordon Levitt’s chapter, while ***The Fat Loss*** picks up with
>   Hartigan and Nancy where the first film left them. So, anything goes
>   basically – characters that appeared in the previous film could
>   return, and we won’t be surprised if others come to an unexpected
>   end...

As you can clearly see, there are stories taking place both **before, during and after** the original story - so watching the original would definitely help.